# How to efficiently add an order variable to a big data frame

Tags: r, performance, split

I have a data frame similar to the following but with 55.000 observations and about 50.000 groups:

```
d <- structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), b = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), .Names = c("a", 
"b"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

As in this data frame each group is again ordered depending on variable "b". I now like to split the data frame according to the grouping variable "a" and add a vector that indicates the ordering number of each element of each sub-data-frame. So the result should look like this:

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), b = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), order = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2)), .Names = c("a", "b", "order"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

I was able to get this result with the split() function an my own gmark() function on the test data frame like this (gmark() assumes the input is already sorted):

```
gmark <- function(input){
  x = 0
  result = vector()
  for(i in input){
    x <- x+1
    result <- append(result, x)
  }
  result
}

x <- split(d, d$a)
x <- lapply(x, function(x){cbind(x, order = gmark(x$b))})
x <- unsplit(x, a)
```

However, **once I apply this to the bigger data frame split() gets very slow** and does not return. Is there a way to get this result on a bigger data frame more efficiently?

Comment: The `for` loop will be faster if you initialize `result` as a numeric vector the exact size that the resulting vector will be (if known).  i.e. if you know `result` is will be a vector of length 50k, initialize it with `result <- numeric(5e4)` instead of `result <- vector()`.

Comment: Thanks. However, my problem is not the gmark() function since every group will have about 1 to 6 observations. Unfortunately split() is stopping my workflow.

Comment: How about something like this: `ta <- as.character(d$a); unlist(sapply(rle(ta)$lengths,seq.int))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with `data.table` package. This'll be much faster.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, order := 1:.N, by=a]
> DT
   a b order
1: A 1     1
2: A 2     2
3: A 1     3
4: B 1     1
5: B 2     2
6: C 1     1
7: C 2     2
```

`:=` is a data.table operator, that adds columns *by reference* (meaning no copy of your data is made). And `.N` is a special variable that contains the length of each group (here, it'll hold 3,2,2 corresponding to A,B,C).

Comment: I assume the original data has to be sorted before performing this on it, correct?

Comment: If you want the order after sorting by `a,b`, then do `setkey(DT, a,b)` before the last line.

Comment: Yes, it worked fine for a sorted input. I'll also try setkey(). It seems the data.table package has quite some nice features that might make my life a little easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not completely runnable. Try this (the second-to-last line makes the difference):

```
d <- data.frame(
    a = sample(LETTERS[1:5],5e4,replace=TRUE),
    b = sample(letters[1:10],5e4,replace=TRUE)) 
x <- split(d,d$a)
y <- lapply(x, function(x){cbind(x, order = 1:nrow(x))})
z <- unsplit(y,d$a)
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look! Where does my code cause an error? The examples as well as the function definition and the function calls are copied from R after testing the example setup. I copied them back from the question text and they work in my environment. In addition the split problem I describe still exists.

Comment: Try running your code in a new R environment, or after `rm(list=ls())`. You `split()` on a variable `a` that is not defined - all that is defined is `d$a`. Nor, actually, is `d`. You have both of these in *your* environment, but we don't, so your code is not fully reproducible. (It's a lot better than many other questions here, though ;-) The `split()` problem probably still exists because you have lots of factor levels, is that possible?

Comment: I see. I updated the question regarding your comments. And yes, as mentioned the number of factor levels is about 50.000.